# does all the node instance created by pm2 will have separate memory and resources?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have a process in which I am generating pdf files and saving in temporary directory .The temporary directory lies in source code repository.
when I am retrieving files by hitting API end point , it returns  no files present sometimes and sometimes it gives me files which are present . we  having this issue in production where  we are using pm2 to create node instance to run the code.

I believe each time request comes , it passes to instance and if instance having files in their temporary directory , it return.

**Problem -- will Each instance  have different local temporary directory or  Each instance will share common directory .**

Comment: yes, they are private processes and cannot share any resources between them. if you have nginx on the backend. you can use ip_hash for handling the request to its own instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In POSIX based systems (Linux, Windows and MacOS) pm2 creates a separate [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) for each instance of your node application. Because they are separate processed they will have separate memory regions and separate temporary file locations.

In order to fix your issue you will need to find a common location where all of your node instances (aka. processes) can read and write the PDF files, making sure that no two process overwrite each others files.